# RAMDISK Partition not getting registered by the kernel

Tags: partitioning, kernel-module, ramdisk

all!
So I've been sleuthing over this problem for the past two days.

I have a ramdisk, and I tried partitioning it using both `parted` and `fdisk`. I also tried to register it using `partprobe` and `kpartx`.

`lsblk` is displaying the partition I made for `cow_ram0` as `cow_ram0p1`. However, the `/dev/cow_ram0p1` file doesn't exist.

Has anyone experienced this before? If so, how'd you solve it?

It doesn't even have to be ramdisk specific. Has anyone ever had the `/dev/` file not appear upon partitioning?

---

### Now, for some details (don't want to get downvoted to oblivion):

The ramdisk is called `cow_ram0`.
So I tried this first: 
`fdisk /dev/cow_ram0` 
I hit `n` for new partition. 
Then, I just hit enter twice to get the first sector number at 2048 and the last one at whatever the last sector is. 
Then I hit `w` to write all these actions.

Then I called `lsblk`. I don't see a partition for the ramdisk. 
So I call `partprobe` and then `kpartx -u /dev/cow_ram0` (calling both because `partprobe` didn't work, and ayy... I am looking into an Issue, so this won't go to master... redundancy won't hurt). 
Now the `lsblk` output actually contains `cow_ram0p1`. 
So I try to mount it, and I get a `/dev/cow_ram0p1 file doesn't exist` error.
I repeat the process above with `parted -a opt /dev/cow_ram0 -t ext4 primary 0% 100%` instead of the `fdisk` stuff above. Same result. 
Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general OS or computer support.

Comment: Apologies. I am doing this in C, but I guess that doesn't make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't contain code, it's not a programming question. I don't see any indication of code anywhere in your post. Looks like it's all OS terminal commands. Did I miss something?

Comment: You're right! It's open-sourced. I'll post it on Unix&Linux, but here's the code if you're interested: https://github.com/utsaslab/crashmonkey/blob/master/code/harness/Tester.cpp#L403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The problem was I had forgotten to set a flag(`max_part`) in the kernel module when inserting it. Hopefully you, the reader, made the same mistake.